# Passing Variable value after specific string in YAML file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, yaml

I have a file which in Yaml format(mentioned below).

values.yml

```
replicaCount: 2
strategy: 
  type: RollingUpdate
  rollingUpdate:
     maxSurge: 1
     maxUnavailable: 1
minReadySeconds: 5
nodeSelector:
       role: nginxplus
image:
  repository: 2xxxxxxxxxxx6.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/miqp-devops
  tag: foo
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Now I want to replace key tag with another value. And the value is coming from a variable.

For eg,

```
 VAR=bar
 echo $VAR
 bar
```

I want something that will edit my values.yml file and replace

tag: foo to tag: bar

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far ? A simple `sed` should easily work in your case

Comment: The right tool for the job is really something like `jq`. (Yes, it generates valid YAML -- all JSON is valid YAML). Otherwise you're subject to all the usual caveats around editing structured data with structure-unaware tools.

Comment: (which is to say that if your input isn't well-formed or the data's representation changes a little, those structure-unaware tools won't know how to deal with it; your `sed`-based answers work for the input only if it remains in *precisely* its current format, but there are other textual versions of that same data that are equally valid data that they won't correctly recognize).

Comment: Rule of thumb for working with HTML/XML/JSON/YAML/... data -- use the right parser for the job.

Answer (score 2):

**sed** approach:

```
var="bar"
sed -i "s/^\([[:space:]]*tag:[[:space:]]*\).*/\1$var/" values.yml
```

The final `values.yml` contents:

```
replicaCount: 2
strategy: 
  type: RollingUpdate
  rollingUpdate:
     maxSurge: 1
     maxUnavailable: 1
minReadySeconds: 5
nodeSelector:
       role: nginxplus
image:
  repository: 2xxxxxxxxxxx6.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/miqp-devops
  tag: bar
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Comment: Note that the input would still be valid -- and semantically identical -- YAML if the file contained `image: {"tag": "foo", "repository": "...", "pullPolicy": "IfNotPresent" }`. There are lots of different ways to write this content within the YAML specification, and this `sed` approach only handles a single one.

Answer (score 2):

To do this robustly (yes, it changes your data's representation, but it remains 100% valid YAML):

```
# This uses/requires the PyYAML library; "pip install PyYAML"
yaml2json() {
  python -c 'import yaml, json, sys; print json.dumps(yaml.safe_load(sys.stdin))'
}

editYaml() {
  local file=$1; shift
  local tempfile=$(mktemp "${file}.XXXXXX")
  local retval

  if jq "$@" < <(yaml2json <"$file") >"$tempfile"; then
    chmod --reference="$file" -- "$tempfile" # on GNU systems, preserve permissions
    mv -- "$tempfile" "$file"
  else
    retval=$?
    rm -f -- "$tempfile"
    return "$retval"
  fi
}

newTag=bar
editYaml values.yml --arg newTag "$newTag" '.image.tag = $newTag'
```

This approach ensures that the same data is converted to the same output, no matter how it's represented -- critical since YAML provides numerous textually-different ways to write the same semantic content.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use perl for this, with the [YAML::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML::Tiny) module

```
cp values.yml values.yml.orig
perl -MYAML::Tiny -se '
    $file = shift @ARGV; 
    $yaml = YAML::Tiny->read($file); 
    $yaml->[0]{image}{tag} = $newtag; 
    $yaml->write($file);
' -- -newtag="bar" values.yml 
cat values.yml
```

```
---
image:
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  repository: 2xxxxxxxxxxx6.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/miqp-devops
  tag: bar
minReadySeconds: '5'
nodeSelector:
  role: nginxplus
replicaCount: '2'
strategy:
  rollingUpdate:
    maxSurge: '1'
    maxUnavailable: '1'
  type: RollingUpdate
```